# Compare same row over two date partitions

Tags: mysql, sql

If data is stored in daily partitions what's the best way to structure a query to identify changes in one value between two different date partitions?

**Date Partition One 06/20**

**Name     Car       Color**       

John     Volvo       Blue       
Mary     Merc      Green       
Paul     BMW       Red

**Date Partition Two 06/21**

**Name     Car       Color**       

John     Volvo       Blue       
Mary     Ford      Green       
Paul     BMW       Red

In this case, between 20th and 21st partitions Mary changed from a Merc to a Ford, so I want to pull out all the values of that row along with before and after value. Returned results should be:

Mary - Merc / Ford - Green

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT A.Name, A.Car, B.Car, A.Color
FROM myTable A INNER JOIN myTable B
ON  A.DatePartition = '20 Jun 2017'
AND B.DatePartition = '21 Jun 2017'
AND A.Name = B.Name 
AND A.Car <> B.Car
```